# forms.$valid showing true, but prints out as false

Tags: javascript, angularjs, validation

I have a strange error and I am not sure what's happening.

When I check an object, I can see that the $valid tag is set to true (and $invalid shows false). But when I print out just that tag (such as object.$valid) it prints false (and object.$invalid prints true).

```
$scope.$watch('ctrl.form', form => {
    console.log('The form is set to: ', form);
    console.log('The form is valid: ', form.$valid);
});
```

[image: console log]

Does anyone know why this might be happening?

Comment: Just curious, what happens if you reverse the order of the console.logs?

Comment: It can be related to the specific of chrome console behavior. When you print the object then expand it you see the object state at the expand time not the print time.

Comment: @sethflowers - No change. It still prints the same values.

Comment: @HamletHakobyan - interesting. I'll put a timeout in and see what happens.

Comment: Well, what's the answer though (why does it happen). Managing code with timeouts is a dicey proposition. If I had to guess, I'd say a digest is the issue? What happens if you put a $scope.apply before the traces?

Comment: @HamletHakobyan - That's very odd - setting a timeout of even 0 forces the correct values to be shown.

Comment: Then the issue is change detection. The timeout 0 thing is a hack to force an update (and unfortunately works so well in a given context that it's all but an accepted practice). Again, the scope.apply may fix it (and then you know the issue is, your scope has not applied the changed values yet).

Comment: @TimConsolazio - Adding $scope.apply doesn't change anything. But adding a timeout does. I am assuming that it is a digest thing and adding a timeout forces it to be ran last. I assume that adding more timeouts would force events to be run sequentially based on the timeout duration.

Comment: It's possible the scope won't apply the changed values in the watch callback, or some such. However, note this might mean, that's not a good place to do operations of this sort. One of the life cycle events might be a better choice. Again, not saying there's no validity to the timeout thing, but it is a hack (I have seen the question many times, "why is there a zero timeout in the angular code"). Unless a developer already has run into this, they'd never know, and may even be inclined to remove it (again, seen that happen). If nothing else, doc the hell out of the line.

Comment: BTW, note that it is "$scope.$apply ( )"

Comment: @TimConsolazio - That's very interesting to keep note of. Thank you for all of the information. If I can't figure out another way to fix this and decide to use the timeout, I will definitely document it.

Comment: @TimConsolazio - $scope.$apply() throws the error - $digest already in progress.

Comment: There it is then, the digest is in progress, so your values haven't updated. One sec, I will look up the old "check for in progress digest" code frag.

Comment: I will post this as an answer to get code formatting etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suspect the issue is, the values are still updating in that function; it is watching for a change in the value, but still hasn't applied the changed values. This can make your code in that handler unpredictable.

Since you mention applying the scope throws the "in progress" error, that seems to be valid (the digest is still working). This code frag checks for an in-progress digest and sidesteps it if necessary.

```
if ( ! $scope.$$phase ) {
   $scope.$apply ();
}
```

Note that "$$" vars in Angular were "private". You could still access them but you're not "supposed" to. This does however have the benefit of not appearing as randomly vague as a zero timeout.

Alternatively, as you've already seen, a 0 timeout can force an update. That's a hack, but it does work and I've seen it used a few times.

Lastly, one of the lifecycle events may be a better choice for these traces, such that you know you're tracing information in the natural flow of the component, where digests are predictable.

Regarding that lifecycle hook, if you're using 1.5 (the last paragraph seems to fit right here and is probably what you want):

```
New: $onChanges

This new hook is similar to ng2’s ngOnChanges. It is called whenever one way bindings are updated, with a hash containing the changes objects.

Prior to this hook you sometimes had to use a $watch in order to do some work whenever a value you’re bound to changes. Using this hook makes things clearer and removes the need to introduce a watch and a dependency on $scope.
```

Comment: I believe that this is indeed the correct answer, so I am marking it as such. But I do need the event to be fired (I need those values), so the timeout is in place until I can figure out a way to process the event later in the life cycles. Thank you for your help and the explanation!

Comment: Check out the edit I just made. I think ngOnChanges may be the way to go for you. Hopefully you're using 1.5.

Comment: It actually works on change just fine. It's on load that is the issue.